# Can't control jQuery animation duration

Tags: jquery, css

I created a slider on a website using the CSS property "clip-path", basically there are two images, one in front of the other and the front picture gets clipped away or "slides" to the left to fully reveal the background. The only way I was able to do this was through using a jQuery step function. I want to control the duration of the animation but keep getting the browser stuck in an infinite loop and without duration working either.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
     $({step: 50}).animate({step: 100}, {
   step: function(val) {
     $('.et_pb_fullwidth_header_0').css("clip-path", "inset(0% " + val + "% 0% 0%)");
   }
})
})
```

".et_pb_fullwidth_header_0" is my image.

According to jQuery's documentation, duration needs to be added in this case after my second parameter i.e. "{step: 100}".

Which would look like this then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
         $({step: 50}).animate({step: 100}, 5000, {
       step: function(val) {
         $('.et_pb_fullwidth_header_0').css("clip-path", "inset(0% " + val + "% 0% 0%)");
       }
    })
    })
```

But that creates an infinite loop on the browser with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at init.s.fx.s.Tween.run (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at Function.S.fx.tick (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
    at ot (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, so let me answer my own question. Lol!

So I needed to set the duration in the code itself, i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
     $({step: 50}).animate({step: 100}, {
duration: 5000,
   step: function(val) {
     $('.et_pb_fullwidth_header_0').css("clip-path", "inset(0% " + val + "% 0% 0%)");
   }
})
})
```

Instead of adding the duration in straight after the second parameter.
Well I hope this helps someone!